# Binding type hinted interface to implementation

Tags: php, laravel, data-binding, ioc-container, lumen

Im building Lumen application, and trying to build it with a very SOLID ethos, with small reusable and swappable packages.

So I have an interface for an abstract resource controller like

```
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

interface ResourceControllerContract
{ 
    public function store(ServerRequestInterface $request);
}
```

In my user resource controller implementation

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest;

final class UserController extends ResourceController 
{    
    public function store(ServerRequest $request)
    {
        $request = $request->getParsedBody();
    }
}
```

Since Guzzle Request already implements Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface, I presumed this could be passed in, but my application kept throwing an exception saying attribute passed to store() should be declared as describe in the ResourceControllerContract

In my service provider in the register method I created a binding like so

```
    $this->app->bind(
        'Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface',
        'GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest'
    );
```

But it still throws the same error, can someone suggest what's going wrong here? It's my first time building an application in this way so forgive me if I missed a simple oversight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So figured it out the UserController implementation should be like so

```
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

final class UserController extends ResourceController 
{    
    public function store(ServerRequest $request)
    {
        $request = $request->getParsedBody();
    }
}
```

And then just leave the binding to bind GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest to Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface

Can someone explain why even though GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest already implements Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface it has to be bound in the laravel service provider. Or does simply php not recognise it as an implementation when being type hinted in a function?

Comment: Because Laravel does not know it exists, or in other words, the dependency injection container has no idea how to inject that class.